# Error while leaving my application xamarin forms android in the background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My solution when I leave the application or leave it in the background gives an error 'The test application stopped', I can not find out where this queue comes from. Does anyone know where this trigger comes from the moment it leaves in the background

Is it something in this part of the code?

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnStart");
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnResume");
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnSleep");
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that error has be anything with the code you posted. That error can happen for many things but usually this occurs when in the background some part of the code tries to update something for the UI and might be this is already disposed by the OS. Use something like Raygun (Crash Report) so you can have a detailed explanation of the issue.

Comment: public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            Finish();
            Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
        }

Comment: I put this command up and it worked, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

This type of errors came along with a specific part of your code, like @apineda mentioned maybe you are using an Android service that is updating some data on your application or it may be there to show a local notification who knows? but the thing I want to imply is that you need to take a look at your code and investigate further which is the part that is making the crash. Here are some tips:

1.- If you are using push notifications that may lead to something!

2.- Check you MainActivity.cs class since this is the one responsible of the Xamarin.Forms activity life cycle.

3.- If you have any timers on your shared code or even a background Task created with `Task.Run` or a `Task.Factory.StartNew()` check those too, deadlocks on Xamarin.Forms applications between the UI thread and background threads are a common thing on Xamarin.Forms.

I hope this helps!